# How to remove the full witdth from <v-card-actions>?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a card that displays a "toolbar" whenever I hover over it

[Reproduction link](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <div class="py-12"></div>
      <v-container>
        <v-menu open-on-hover location="top" transition="slide-y-transition">
          <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
            <v-card v-bind="props" variant="outlined">
              <v-card-title>Card goes here</v-card-title>
            </v-card>
          </template>

          <v-card variant="outlined" class="ml-4">
            <v-card-actions>
              <v-btn icon="mdi-link-variant-minus" size="small" color="error" />
              <v-btn icon="mdi-arrow-expand" size="small" color="primary" class="ml-4" />
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </v-menu>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

But this "toolbar" should not expand to full width. I want it to be like a tab, e.g.

[image]

Adding the `d-inline-block` helper class to `v-card-actions` or to its parent `v-card` didn't help. I'm basically looking for

```html
<div style="background:red">I don't want this</div>
<div style="display: inline-block; background:red; margin-top: 24px">I want this</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`width: fit-content;` for the toolbar parent block might solve it.

[image]

Comment: ah yes, that solved it :) Just looking for the Vuetify css class ...